# Tabs don't switch on click

Tags: javascript, php, html, tabs

I have two tabs `review` and `highlights`. When the website loads the highlights tab is active or is already clicked by default, but the data displayed on it is both of `highlights` and `reviews`. When I click on `reviews` tab it has the same data of both the tabs. What am I doing wrong in my code so it's displaying data of both tabs in each of review and highlights tab rather only displaying data each of their own?

My code:

```html
<?php
echo " <div class='nav nav-tabs' id='nav-tab' role='tablist'>";
    echo "<a class='nav-link active' id='nav-highlights-tab' data-toggle='tab' href='#nav-highlights' role='tab' aria-controls='nav-highlights' aria-selected='true'>Highlights</a>";
    echo "<a class='nav-link' id='nav-review-tab' data-toggle='tab' href='#nav-reviews' role='tab' aria-controls='nav-reviews' aria-selected='false'>Reviews</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</nav>";
    echo "<div class='tab-content' id='nav-tabContent'>";
    echo "<div class='tab-pane fade show active' id='nav-highlights' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='nav-highlights-tab'>";
    /// getRestaurantHighlights($result['res_id']) .
    echo "<p>highlights</p>";

    "</div>";
    echo "<div class='tab-pane fade' id='nav-reviews' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='nav-reviews-tab'>";
    //getRestaurantReviews($result['res_id']) .
    echo "<p>reviews</p>";
    "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";


echo "<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchAnything').on('keyup', function () {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('#myDIV *').filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
    });
  });

</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Man for your better work...

Don´t use `echo..` so much

Use `echo` only on **php function** and **variables** but definetly not on a html tags

```
<nav>
  <div class='nav nav-tabs' id='nav-tab' role='tablist'>
   <a class='nav-link active' id='nav-highlights-tab' data-toggle='tab' href='#nav-highlights' role='tab' aria-controls='nav-highlights' aria-selected='true'>Highlights</a>
  <a class='nav-link' id='nav-review-tab' data-toggle='tab' href='#nav-reviews' role='tab' aria-controls='nav-reviews' aria-selected='false'>Reviews</a>
 </div>
</nav>

<div class='tab-content' id='nav-tabContent'>

    <div class='tab-pane fade show active' id='nav-highlights' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='nav-highlights-tab'>

          <div class='tab-pane fade' id='nav-reviews' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='nav-reviews-tab'>
<?php echo getRestaurantReviews($result['res_id']);  ?>  
     </div>

     <p>reviews</p>
```

Comment: I was wondering where did you write highlights to be printed? In highlight section you added `<p>reviews</p>` but there is no highlights to be printed. Yes, I will make sure to use `echo` only when it's needed. I actually have some condition before all these run it's why I put inside `echo`.